# Initializing a vanilla C struct

Tags: c++, c

I want to add a C-style struct to a C++ header and use it in a C function. But this is not working:

```
struct Vertex {
float Position[2];
float Color[4];
};

struct Square{
Vertex vertices[4];
};
```

Elsewhere:

```
float color[4]={rColor, gColor, bColor, alpha};
float halfsize=(float)size/2;

Square square= {
    {{halfsize,halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}},
    {{halfsize,-halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}}, //error on this line
    {{-halfsize,-halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}},
    {{-halfsize,halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}}
};
```

Reports "Excess elements in struct initializer" on the second line.

On a related note, is there a more efficient way to pass in the array `color` to the `square` set?

Comment: [Adding an extra brace worked](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1YHz9f$3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [add an extra brace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1YHz9f$3) for the initializer for `Vertex vertices[4];`

```
                \/   
Square square= {{
    {{halfsize,halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}},
    {{halfsize,-halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}}, //error on this line
    {{-halfsize,-halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}},
    {{-halfsize,halfsize},{color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}}
}};
^
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answerer has mentioned, you should add an extra brace and then things will work.

However, you also ask if this is a more efficient way to pass in `color`.

I'm afraid I don't think there there is. Since neither C nor C++ keep track of the length of an array and since there is no construct for splicing arrays you cannot indicate to the compiler that you want a certain section of the array to be copied.

But what do you really mean by efficient? If you mean, "Is there a way which will execute faster?" Then the answer is almost certainly no. This initialization will be very quick.

If you mean, "Is there a way which can be written with fewer lines of code?" Then the answer again is probably no. Six lines is pretty tight.

Granted, you are using a C++ header, so I'd think you must also be using a C++ compiler so it seems pointless to build this part of the code in pure C. You could make `color` into an STL vector and then build some constructors for `Square` and `Vertex` which initialize off of this vector. It would not take significantly more code and may reduce the probability of accidental mistakes.

Alternatively, if you're set on C and plan on having this code come up time and again, you could consider using a macro (either as below, or for the whole bloody thing, but then I'd say it would be better to have it in a function):

```
#define RGB_INIT {color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]}
```

Though macros do have their dangers.

Comment: i found that replacing the `color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]` with just `*color` worked quite well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255621/pointing-at-an-array-to-get-all-its-contents

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of that construct, @SebbyJohanns. Have you looked to see if it initializes _all_ the elements?

Comment: For those reading this, the result of the question linked above is that `*color` does not work in this way.