# Pointing at an array to get all its contents

Tags: c++, c

So, arrays are pointers to their first element.

`float color[4]={rColor, gColor, bColor, alpha};`

Thus, just plain `color` points to `&color[0]`;

Now suppose I have a struct thusly:

```
struct Colors{
float color[4];
};
```

Now I have found I can do this quite fine:

```
Colors myColor={{*color}};
```

I could also just do this:

```
Colors myColor={{color[0]}};
```

I am only pointing at one element, but the struct expects 4, so it keeps looking past this element.

First, I want to check that is fine to do, legal and okay. Obviously if you are passing a large array, this is quite convenient on the syntax and typing.

Second, I want to verify the reasoning about why this works. Since `color` alone is a pointer, the `*` is an indirection operator that retrieves the memory pointed to, thus, the array. So essentially we get the entire array by just calling its pointer with indirection. Correct?

Comment: No, arrays are not pointers. They're entirely different beasts. Well, not _entirely_, perhaps.

Comment: @DanielFischer in C++; in C, they are quite the same

Comment: The name of an array is a pointer to its first element, from everything I have read. And this is true in both C and C++.

Comment: @JanDvorak No, they are not. Try passing a `char**` to a function expecting a `char (*)[17]`.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns In most contexts (except as the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or `&`), the array name is _converted_ to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns, no this is not true in any of those two. Play around with `sizeof color` and you will see.

Comment: An array is a block of memory. A pointer is an address in memory. These are clearly not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intializers of structures, unions and arrays have the particular property that elements that are omitted from it are initialized with `0`.

To initialize a whole structure as your `Colors` you can also use any other object of that same type.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "To initialize a whole structure as your Colors you can also use any other object of that same type."

Comment: @SebbyJohanns `Colors myColor = {...};` and later, `Colors myOtherColor = myColor;`.

Answer (score 1):

if you initialize Colors like this

```
Colors myColor={{*color}};
```

you copy the first array element of the color array the rest will be initialized with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using this test code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    int i;
    int color[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int ted[4]={*color};

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%d ",ted[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

One can easily verify that only the first element of `ted` is being initialized by your code. This is because `*color` points only to the first element of `color`. So the initialization list is only one item long.

Since neither C nor C++ knows the length of an array it is not possible for the compiler to automagically copy ever element of the array in the way you hope.